# How to convert sets of ODE to difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, control-theory, difference-sets

I have successful developed a continuous mathematical model for my physical system. The model comprises of sets of 7 nonlinear ODE. My objective is to transform the continuous-time ODE into a set of discrete-time difference equations and implement a digital controller for the system.

I will like to know the method/ technique for converting sets of ODE to discrete-time equations.

Example of the ODE is shown below.

$\frac{dT_1}{dt} = \frac{\frac{A(T_2 - T_1)}{M_1.C_v} + \frac{T_1}{M_1}.\frac{dM_1}{dt} }{1 + \frac{T_1.M_1}{vol.P}}$

$\frac{dT_2}{dt} =  A(T_2 - T_1) + T_2^4$

$\frac{dM_1}{dt} = -A_v.\rho_{gas}.u$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = g.\rho_{air}.vol - M_1 - Drag$

$ \frac{dh}{dt} = V$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you give an example for an ODE like the ones you want to transform?

Comment: @Tee you can edit your question to add the equation, it will be easier if you do so.

Comment: thanks, @razivo I have updated the question with an example of the sets of ODE i want to convert to the difference equation

Comment: You can use any Runge-Kutta method or any linear multi-step method with fixed step-size. They do exactly that, give a discretized system that follows closely the exact solution.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann